# ReWrite в htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

у меня формируется адрес `site.ru/lk/confirmation.php?code=codetext`
как через Rewrite его можно привести к виду

```
site.ru/lk/confirmatio/codetext
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^lk/confirmation/(.+)$ /lk/confirmation.php?code=$1
```

Comment: Что то все равно пишет ошибку 404.
Это надо в htaccess файл в корне сайта добавлять или можно в папке с php файлом?

Comment: чуть поправил и получилось, спасибо